# Galleria full screen slider hides the contents below the slider and also the scrolling bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, galleria

We are using Galleria full screen slider but it hides the contents below the slider.

The slider is at http://uploadmyfiles.com/galleria/

The following css is causing the problem.

```
.galleria-theme-fullscreen {
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
background: #000;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

If I modify it then the slider height becomes 0 and slider not working. Any solution?

Thanks in advance.